# Is 'We promise your level up' grammatical when used in an ad?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions

> We promise your level up

We intended to use this expression to draw a particular crowd as an ads of an institute(or a cram school called "hakwon").

I'm asking this of you for a school assignment with my group in college. Sure, there's a lot of items for this. The problem is I think it's a wrong sentence, but all but me think it is good. So we planned to submit our assignment for that phrase. I posted this question for persuading my members lastly into using other units for a reasonable reason.

"We will bring your level up" or "we will get your level up" feels just fine. Even though I know this structure like "promise sth to sb" is possible, but I feel like "your level up" is not compatible with the verb "promise" as an object, because there are phrasal verbs like bring sth up or get sth up, but there isn't a thing like "promise sth up". And I googled the phrase "promise your level up" but 8 came out in search results. So I think it is wrong. What about you?

Comment: Don't you have somebody on your faculty who can answer this? If you don't, how can you suppose we would be comfortable helping you promote your school?

Comment: I'm doing this for a school assignment with my group in collage. Sure, there's a lot of items for this. The problem is I think it's a wrong sentence, but all but me think it is good. So we planned to submit our assignment for that phrase. I posted this question for persuading my members lastly into using other units for a reasonable reason.

Comment: Why do *you* think it's wrong.

Comment: "We will bring your level up" or "we will get your level up" feels just fine. Even though I know this structure like "promise sth to sb" is possible, but I feel like "your level up" is not compatible with the verb "promise" as an object, because there are phrasal verbs like bring sth up or get sth up, but there isn't a thing like "promise sth up". And I googled the phrase "promise your level up" but 8 came out in search results. So I think it is wrong.

Comment: Would you [edit] your question to include the information from your comments please?  It would make it much easier for someone to write an answer that will be useful to you.

Comment: I'm really happy that you got an answer that is helpful to you so quickly, but you may want to wait a little while longer before you accept an answer. This post on [meta] explains why: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/9161 I have edited your title to make it a little more interesting to people browsing the questions. It's a good idea to make your title stand out from other questions so that someone will think "I can answer that!" and click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct; the sentence is wrong, and there are a number of problems with it.  Yes, [**level up** is an expression](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/level-up), but it's not being used correctly here.

*Level up* is a verb phrase.  "Your" is only used with nouns or noun phrases: *your level, your skills, your ability*, etc.  (I realize English can be confusing because so many words, like *level*, can function as nouns or verbs, but in this case it's a verb.)  "Level up" just means something like "improve", so you can see how "your improve" doesn't make sense.

The normal structure used with *promise* is something like

- **We promise *noun*** (for example, "We promise improvement")
- **We promise to *verb*** (for example, "We promise to improve") or
- **We promise that *clause*** (for example, "We promise that we will improve")

You can see how "your level up" doesn't match any of those.  Possible alternatives that do work are

- **We promise to bring your level up**
- **We promise that you will level up**

Other problems with the sentence are that *promise* isn't really the right word to use in this context; in the context of promises made by a business to its customers, **[guarantee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guarantee)** is a more idiomatic word choice.

Also, **level up** is a very slangy, informal choice of words, and is probably not appropriate for an ad, unless the entire ad is very informal, and "We promise" sounds relatively formal.  "Bring your level up" is a better fit.  (Note that *level* is a noun in this context!)